# Google API PHP throws "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded"

Tags: php, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-php-client, google-signin

I succesfully integrated a Google Login in my page. In the developer dashboard I listed two possible callback urls. In the JSON file, both are listed, too:

1. https://www.website.com/en/oauth2/google
2. https://www.website.com/de/oauth2/google

In order to know which language version of the website he visited before the login, the page choses the correct callback url.

But only the first URL (with en) will work. If the other one is called, then the API returns "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded".

If I swap around the callback urls, then it is the "de" version which will work. So it is always the first one.

Any hints what goes wrong here, would be very much appreciated!

This is the code in the callback.php. It will break when the second callback url is used, but will work flawlessly on the first url.

```
require_once '/google-api-php-client/vendor/autoload.php';

$client=new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig('/client_id.json');
$client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
$access_token=$client->getAccessToken($access_token);

// Get user date from Google+
$plus = new Google_Service_Plus($client);
$user = $plus->people->get('me'); // <--- this is where it breaks.
```

Comment: Please include your code this is not enough information to help diagnose the problem http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Done. The code really isn't that complicated. Also: It works flawlessly. I suppose a very crazy bug in Google+ API.

Comment: do a var dump on client.   Cant remember how you do that in PHP.  getAccessToken doesn't take any paramaters as far as i can see.  that and you haven't supplied a redirect uri.   https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/37adb8a6f4d4b27b9900d62d67bf1d54995a755c/examples/url-shortener.php

Comment: I do not need to supply a redirect – this is the callback-code NOT the login code. It redirects at a later stage. Again: This code works wonderfully but not with the second callback url.

I solved it differently now where I store the language in a SESSION variable and then redirecting according to this. By doing so, I only need ONE callback url and that just works.

Comment: well  "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded" means that you are not logged in so I would suggest that also means it doesn't just work.  check $client does it contain the access token?

Comment: But that's not the case. As written above, it works wonderfully with the FIRST callback-url listed. The only issue is that it did not work with the second callback url (which points to exactly the same php-file).

Comment: I think that the original problem was that you missed setting the access token to the client once you authenticated. `$client->setAccessToken($_SESSION["access_token"]);`

Comment: Again: If that would be the case then the code should have never worked. But it only did not work on the second callback url. When I use the second backlink, I do not even get a proper token back in the first place I found out.